# 10.8 Replacement for CGRegisterScreenRefreshCallback

Tags: quartz-2d

Apple is pretty bad about making deprecations easy to comply with, since about 90% of the time they offer no replacement suggestion in the documentation (except for the most commonly used apis).

10.8 deprecates a slew of Quartz Display apis, including CGRegisterScreenRefreshCallback.  Does anyone know what we're supposed to use now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple says CGDisplayStream, not that there's any documentation to that effect (or any documentation for Display Stream, for that matter).